# Python selenium send_keys emoji support

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use selenium's send_keys to send emoji characters to a text box with the following python code.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
browser.get("https://www.google.co.in")
time.sleep(5)
working = browser.find_element_by_id('lst-ib')
text = u'Python is '
working.send_keys(text)
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "smiley.py", line 30, in <module>
    working.send_keys(text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 347, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 491, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 238, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(value)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: missing command parameters
```

Upon searching I found out that selenium send_keys only support single byte characters. But I would like to know, if there is any alternative way I could achieve this.

I have tried using CTRl + C and CTRL + V combinations and it is working. But sometimes the clipboard contents gets changed before pasting (copy and paste happens almost immediately).

I could not set the value of the field using execute_script either, as it is not an input element but a span. I could set inner_text but useless in my use case.

**UPDATE:**
I have used some workarounds to tackle the clipboard overwritten issue. The working code is provided below.

```
schedule = urllib2.urlopen(request,context=ctx)
text = schedule.read().decode('utf-8')
elem = browser.find_element_by_class_name(xpathObj['commentLink'])
elem.click()
time.sleep(2)
ActionChains(browser).send_keys('a').perform()
time.sleep(2)
copy_attempt = 0
while True:
    span_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpathObj['commentSpan'])
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = arguments[1]", span_element, text)
    time.sleep(2)
    ActionChains(browser).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('a').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
    time.sleep(1)
    ActionChains(browser).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('c').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('V').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
    time.sleep(1)
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    text1 = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_UNICODETEXT)
    emoji_pattern = re.compile(
        u"(\ud83d[\ude00-\ude4f])|"  # emoticons
        u"(\ud83c[\udf00-\uffff])|"  # symbols & pictographs (1 of 2)
        u"(\ud83d[\u0000-\uddff])|"  # symbols & pictographs (2 of 2)
        u"(\ud83d[\ude80-\udeff])|"  # transport & map symbols
        u"(\ud83c[\udde0-\uddff])"   # flags (iOS)
        "+", flags=re.UNICODE)
    s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,emoji_pattern.sub(r'', text), emoji_pattern.sub(r'', text1))
    if (s.ratio() < 1.0):
        if (copy_attempt < 5):
            copy_attempt = copy_attempt + 1
            continue
        else:
            break
    else:
        ActionChains(browser).send_keys(Keys.RETURN).perform()
        time.sleep(3)
        break
time.sleep(3)
```

Thank you All.

Comment: Your keyboard sends a stream of bytes when typing high Unicode characters. Try encoding it in UTF-8 or UTF-16 and see if it works.

Answer (score 4):

With the current version of the chrome driver (2.32), the method `send_keys` only supports characters from the [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)).

If you wish to type an emoji, you'll have to use a script injection to write your text in the desired input via the `value` property. You'll also have to dispatch the `change` event to notify the listeners :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in")

time.sleep(5)

JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT = """
  var elm = arguments[0], txt = arguments[1];
  elm.value += txt;
  elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
  """

elem = driver.find_element_by_id('lst-ib')
text = u'\ud83d\udc4d'

driver.execute_script(JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT, elem, text)
```

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response. Thank you for your help.  I have used your code along with copy paste (once pasted I compare the clipboard contents with the variable) and it is working fine now. Will paste the code in question itself.

Comment: Regrettably, this does not work for me. I am trying to input a string containing characters from all unicode blocks which looks like this: ␡ÆĦǣʨ˧͚ΔѨ֍ࢥޛچضغ߷ࠇउगऴ৳ਸ਼ષନஹౙಯ൷ෂท໖༺ဪჭᆅቘᎆᎹᐇᚙᛤᜇᜰᝇᝧ៘ᢆᣢᢆᢆᡆᤗᥘᦜ᧻ᨋᩗ᪶ᬑᮼᯥᰒᱫᲇ᳄᳷ᵹᶋ᷼ỸὮ※ₘ₹⃟™ↈ↹∰⌦␥⑆⓭╃▙◍♅❦⟗⟹⡕⥇⧉⩷⭖Ⱗⱷ⳧ⴥⵥⶻⷵ⸾⻭⽧⿷〶きラ鏡狐ㄦㅶ㆗ㆧ㇡ㇺ㈿㍇㑴䷺亘ꁚ꓂ꓩꔫꚖꚼ꜕Ꝧꠚ꠷ꡪꢸꣶꤥꥅꥺ꧄ꧨꩆꩶ꫞ꫩꬤꭔꮚ꯹걗ퟶ珞ﬦﮖ︌︗︩︾﹠ﻉﾚ, and I get WebDriverException: Message: missing command parameters

Comment: as I remember the u'string' prefix is redundant in python3, because it uses Unicode by default, is this python2? am I right?