# How to input "Hot dog" emoji using Python Selenium send_keys

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using python with selenium to send "Hot dog" emoji into an input (link for emoji here: [Hot dog emoji](https://emojipedia.org/hot-dog/) .
And this's my code:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
i = ''.decode("utf-8")
elem.send_keys(i)
```

Then I got this error:

```
File "E:/MMO/MyTools/Facebook/test.py", line 35, in facebook_login
elem.send_keys(i)
File "C:\Users\Ab\facebookenv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 352, in send_keys
'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
File "C:\Users\Ab\facebookenv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 501, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "C:\Users\Ab\facebookenv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 308, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\Ab\facebookenv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 165, in check_response raise exception_class(value)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: missing command parameters
```

What's happening?

Comment: Will this page be of any help? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45330640/python-selenium-send-keys-emoji-support

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python selenium send\_keys emoji support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45330640/python-selenium-send-keys-emoji-support)

Answer (score 1):

use clipboard

```
import pyperclip
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

pyperclip.copy("some text")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//TEXTAREA[@class='text']")).click().send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,'v').perform()
```